# Does ghc-mod support ghcjs?

Tags: haskell-stack, ghcjs, ghc-mod

As of May 2016, does ghc-mod support projects compiled with ghcjs?

I realise that in a lot of cases, the source is the same, but this is not the case when working with ghcjs-dom library.

I currently have 2 project folders, configured with stack. From outside these folders:

```
ghc-mod check folder1/executable/Main.hs
```

works perfectly. The stack.yaml file here specifies ghc-7.10.2

```
ghc-mod check folder2/executable/Main.hs
```

fails. The stack.yaml file here specifies ghcjs-0.2.0.0_ghc-7.10.2

Is this expected behaviour? I can't tell frrm the feature requests and wikis what the current state is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently - https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs/issues/271

Note that this is actually pretty tricky as ghc-mod would need to be linked with ghcjs.  As far as I know ghcjsi is the only such tool to work with ghcjs

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure its tricky: ghc-mod and ghcjs are some of the most inspiring bits of software I've ever come across. I'd offer to help, but I have about zero knowledge of javascript, or the internals of ghcjs or ghc-mod. I've only been driven to use ghcjs because ghcjs-dom doesn't support canvas elements using ghc (due to the underlying webkitgtk library)